# Guestbook script

Tags: php, object-oriented

I'm brand new at OOP PHP and I would like to get as many of the coding conventions right as fast as possible. I made this tiny guestbook script, and I would like to know if there's anything not done as it should.

**Index.php:**

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "oop";
$host = "localhost";

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database);
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include("views/gaestebog.php");
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Guestbook.php, the class:**

```
<?php
class Gaestebog {

    public function __contruct() {

    }

    public function getPosts() {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gaestebog");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row['navn'].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row['besked'].'</td>
            </tr>
            ';
        }
    }

    public function addPost($navn, $besked) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO gaestebog VALUES('', '$navn', '$besked')");
    }
}
?>
```

**guestbook.php, the view:**

```
<?php
include("classes/Gaestebog.php");
$gaestebog = new Gaestebog();
if (isset($_POST['opret'])) {
    $navn = $_POST['navn'];
    $besked = $_POST['besked'];
    $gaestebog->addPost($navn, $besked);
}
?>
<table>
    <?php
    $gaestebog->getPosts();
    ?>
</table>

<hr />

<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Navn:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="navn" value="Patrick" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Besked:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="besked" value="Hej med dig !!" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="opret" value="Opret" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the PHP manual online about your use of database operations for MySQL for example `mysql_query()` is no longer suggested http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php one of the alternatives is to use the `mysqli` interface with is OOP.

Comment: instead of using `mysql` go for `mysqli` or `PDO`. Use parameterized query. make a use of database abstraction class instead of using core database functions in your classes. Thats all I can think of now

Comment: When i use mysqli, should i be creating a new object inside every class of the mysqli connection?

Comment: @PatrickReck: No, you create one instance, and pass it around you objects/methods.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the first, and most obvious thing to note is your vulnerability to **SQL injection**.

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new
>   code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the
>   [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the
>   [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared
>   statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use
>   [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this
>   article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose
>   PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Also, it's considered good practice to separate logic from presentation (i.e. PHP from HTML).

Comment: How would i separate it even more than i've done here?

Comment: @PatrickReck: Well, you need very little PHP code on your **view** or **template** (that's what it's called). Form processing, heavy business logic, database interactions, those should be on their own files, with zero HTML output on them.

Answer (score 6):

This is often called procedural programming with outdated libraries:

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database);
```

And that was only the beginning of your script. Maybe it's better you don't focus so much on fancy programming terms but instead just get the work done.

Example *`guestbook.php`*:

```
<?php
require('bootstrap.php');

$page = new Htmlpage('My Guestbook');
$page->start($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$gaestebog = new Gaestebog();

echo '<table border="1">';

foreach ($gaestebog->getPosts() as $post)
{
    $row = new Htmlencoded($post);

    echo <<<OUT
            <tr>
                <td>$row['navn']</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>$row['besked']</td>
            </tr>
OUT;
}
echo '</table>';

$page->closeRequest();
?>
```

Otherwise if you want to learn about object oriented programming, use object interfaces and practice, practice, practice.

Start with something simple, like a *form field*. Not with a whole script.

Answer (score 6):

Couple of points:

- Don't use the deprecated mysql library, try PDO or MySQLi instead
- `__contruct()` has a typo, should be `__construct()`.
- Don't return raw HTML from get methods such as `getPosts()`, instead return an array of posts and let the view create HTML if that's the output you want
- Protect against, SQL Injection, your `INSERT` query is vulnerable

Answer (score 3):

This is not at all OOP. guestbook.php has a class and contains few methods but that doesn't mean that you are applying OO concepts. I am afraid that your example has little scope to apply OO. Few improvements you can do here, separate presentation logic from getPosts().

Thus getPosts() will be responsible for retrieving posts from db and then create separate methods how you want to present the data, for example getPostInTabularFormat(), getPostInDivformat() etc...

Also you can convert the Form in the view to a class. take a look at [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18241/oop-php-form-ok)